# How do I turn a string into the name of an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, metaprogramming, local-variables

I've think I've created multiple arrays from strings but if I try to inspect the array I receive an error.

```
File.open("livestock.txt", "r") do |file|
    file.readlines.each do |x|

        if x.match(/:*:/)
            # puts x.inspect
            # strip string
            x.gsub!(/[^A-Za-z]/, '')
            x.downcase!
            puts x.inspect
            x = Array.new(){Hash.new}
            # puts x.inspect
            pigs.inspect
        else
            # puts "no"
        end

    end
end


animals.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <main>': undefined local variable or method `pigs' for main:Object (NameError)
    from animals.rb:2:in `each'
    from animals.rb:2:in `block in <main>'
    from animals.rb:1:in `open'
    from animals.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

Ideally I want to create pigs =[]
then add hashes to this array such as:

```
pigs = [{"name"=>"peggy", "id"=>1, "owner"=>"wolcott farms"},
{"name"=>"sue", "id"=>2, "owner"=>"blue moon farms"},
{"name"=>"eddie", "id"=>3, "owner"=>"sunrise farms"}
]
```

and the same for cows, etc.

my text file animals.txt is

```
::pigs::  
name, id, owner
peggy, 1, wolcott farms 
sue, 2, blue moon farms
eddie, 3, sunrise farms

::cows:: 
name, id, owner 
dee, 3, black hat farms 
sunny, 2, blue moon farms 
bess, 4, wolcott farms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Parse Text, Then Assign Using Instance Variables

You can't use local variables, but you can use [Object#instance_variable_get](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get) and [Object#instance_variable_set](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set) to do this kind of metaprogramming. For example:

```
str     = File.read '/tmp/livestock.txt'
records = str.split /\n\n+/
records.map! { |r| r.split /\n/ }
records.map do |r| 
  var    = ?@ << r.shift.strip.delete(?:)
  fields = r.shift.strip.scan /[^,]+/
  hashes = r.map { |e| e.split(?,).flat_map &:strip }.
             map { |e| fields.zip e }.
             map &:to_h
  instance_variable_set var,
    instance_variable_get(var).to_a.push(hashes).flatten!
end;

# The data is now stored correctly in the following instance variables.
@pigs
@cows
```

### Caveat

Note that if *@pigs* or *@cows* already exist because you're testing in the REPL, your results may not be what you expect. Make sure you invoke [Object#remove_instance_variable](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-remove_instance_variable), set your variables to nil, or create a new instance of your class between tests.

Comment: thanks for your time::When I inspect the records I see the following output [["peggy, 1, wolcott farms ", "sue, 2, blue moon farms", "eddie, 3, sunrise farms"], ["dee, 3, black hat farms ", "sunny, 2, blue moon farms ", "bess, 4, wolcott farms"]] which is an array of array but not of hashes. Is this possible as illustrated in my first post?

Comment: @Voss You're incorrectly looking at the return value, rather than the variables containing the hashes. Look at *@pigs* and *@cows*, and ignore the return value from the mapping block.

Comment: Yes you're right! Sorry about that. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Since Ruby v1.8 it has not been possible to create local variables. Instance variables, yes (using [Object#instance_variable_set](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set)), local variables, no.

@CodeGnome has given one way to create instance variables with given names. I don't think a collection of instance variables is the appropriate data structure however. I would suggest you consider using a hash instead. You could do that as follows.

**Code**

```
def doit(fname)
  File.read(fname).
       split(/\n{2,}/). # split paragraphs
       each_with_object({}) do |s,h|
         outer_key, inner_key_names, *inner_values = s.split(/\n/)
         inner_keys = inner_key_names.split(/,\s+/)
         h[outer_key[/(?<=::)[^:]+/]] =
           inner_values.each_with_object([]) { |values_str, a|
             a << inner_keys.zip(values_str.split(/,\s+/)).to_h }
       end
end
```

**Example**

First let's create your file.

```
FName = "animals.txt"

data =<<_
::pigs::  
name, id, owner
peggy, 1, wolcott farms 
sue, 2, blue moon farms
eddie, 3, sunrise farms

::cows:: 
name, id, owner 
dee, 3, black hat farms 
sunny, 2, blue moon farms 
bess, 4, wolcott farms
_

File.write(FName, data)
  #=> 203
```

Now execute the method on this file.

```
doit(FName)
  #=> {"pigs"=>[{"name"=>"peggy", "id"=>"1", "owner"=>"wolcott farms "},
  #             {"name"=>"sue", "id"=>"2", "owner"=>"blue moon farms"},
  #             {"name"=>"eddie", "id"=>"3", "owner"=>"sunrise farms"}],
  #    "cows"=>[{"name"=>"dee", "id"=>"3", "owner "=>"black hat farms "},
  #             {"name"=>"sunny", "id"=>"2", "owner "=>"blue moon farms "},
  #             {"name"=>"bess", "id"=>"4", "owner "=>"wolcott farms"}]}
```

**Explanation**

The steps are as follows.

```
b = File.read(FName).split(/\n{2,}/)
  #=> ["::pigs::  \nname, id, owner\npeggy, 1, wolcott farms \nsue, 2, blue moon farms\neddie, 3, sunrise farms",
  #    "::cows:: \nname, id, owner \ndee, 3, black hat farms \nsunny, 2, blue moon farms \nbess, 4, wolcott farms\n"]
```

Next we have

```
enum = b.each_with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["::pigs::  \nname, id, owner\npeggy, 1, wolcott farms \nsue, 2, blue moon farms\neddie, 3, sunrise farms",
  #                  "::cows:: \nname, id, owner \ndee, 3, black hat farms \nsunny, 2, blue moon farms \nbess, 4, wolcott farms\n"]:each_with_object({})>
```

We can convert `enum` to an array to see the values it will generate and pass to its block:

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [["::pigs::  \nname, id, owner\npeggy, 1, wolcott farms \nsue, 2, blue moon farms\neddie, 3, sunrise farms", {}],
  #    ["::cows:: \nname, id, owner \ndee, 3, black hat farms \nsunny, 2, blue moon farms \nbess, 4, wolcott farms\n", {}]] The empty arrays above will be populated as the calculations proceed.
```

We now pass the first element of `enum` to the block and assign the block variables

```
s,h = enum.next
  #=> ["::pigs::  \nname, id, owner\npeggy, 1, wolcott farms \nsue, 2, blue moon farms\neddie, 3, sunrise farms", {}] 
s #=> "::pigs::  \nname, id, owner\npeggy, 1, wolcott farms \nsue, 2, blue moon farms\neddie, 3, sunrise farms" 
h => {}
```

The value of `h`, an empty hash, will be modified by the block, as will be shown.

The block calculations are now performed for these values of `s` and `h`.

```
outer_key, inner_key_names, *inner_values = s.split(/\n/)
  #=> ["::pigs::  ",
  #    "name, id, owner",
  #    "peggy, 1, wolcott farms ",
  #    "sue, 2, blue moon farms", "eddie, 3, sunrise farms"]
outer_key
  #=> "::pigs::  " 
inner_key_names
  #=> "name, id, owner" 
inner_values
  #=> ["peggy, 1, wolcott farms ",
  #    "sue, 2, blue moon farms",
  #    "eddie, 3, sunrise farms"] 
inner_keys = inner_key_names.split(/,\s+/)
  #=> ["name", "id", "owner"]
h[outer_key[/(?<=::)[^:]+/]] =
  inner_values.each_with_object([]) { |values_str, a|
    a << inner_keys.zip(values_str.split(/,\s+/)).to_h }
  # => [{"name"=>"peggy", "id"=>"1", "owner"=>"wolcott farms "},
  #     {"name"=>"sue", "id"=>"2", "owner"=>"blue moon farms"},
  #     {"name"=>"eddie", "id"=>"3", "owner"=>"sunrise farms"}] 
h #=> {"pigs"=>[{"name"=>"peggy", "id"=>"1", "owner"=>"wolcott farms "},
  #   {"name"=>"sue", "id"=>"2", "owner"=>"blue moon farms"},
  #   {"name"=>"eddie", "id"=>"3", "owner"=>"sunrise farms"}]}
```

Let's examine this last calculation more closely.

```
outer_key[/(?<=::)[^:]+/]
  #=> "pigs"
enum1 = inner_values.each_with_object([])
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["peggy, 1, wolcott farms ", "sue, 2, blue moon farms",
  #                  "eddie, 3, sunrise farms"]:each_with_object([])> 
enum1.to_a
  #=> [["peggy, 1, wolcott farms ", []],
  #    ["sue, 2, blue moon farms", []],
  #    ["eddie, 3, sunrise farms", []]]
```

The first element generated by `enum1` is passed to the block and the block variables are assigned.

```
values_str, a = enum1.next
  #=> ["peggy, 1, wolcott farms ", []] 
values_str
  #=> "peggy, 1, wolcott farms "
a #=> []
```

The block calculations are now performed.

```
b = inner_keys.zip(values_str.split(/,\s+/))
  #=> ["name", "id", "owner"].zip(["peggy", "1", "wolcott farms "])
  #=> [["name", "peggy"], ["id", "1"], ["owner", "wolcott farms "]]
c = b.to_h
  #=> {"name"=>"peggy", "id"=>"1", "owner"=>"wolcott farms "}
a << c
  #=> [{"name"=>"peggy", "id"=>"1", "owner"=>"wolcott farms "}]
```

The remaining two elements generated by `enum1` are treated similarly, resulting in

```
h #=> {"pigs"=>[{"name"=>"peggy", "id"=>"1", "owner"=>"wolcott farms "},
  #             {"name"=>"sue", "id"=>"2", "owner"=>"blue moon farms"},
  #             {"name"=>"eddie", "id"=>"3", "owner"=>"sunrise farms"}]
```

The remaining calculations (for cows) are similar.

**@pigs and @cows**

If you insist on having those instance variables it is easy to generate them from the hash constructed above.

```
h = {"pigs"=>[{"name"=>"peggy", "id"=>"1", "owner"=>"wolcott farms "},
              {"name"=>"sue", "id"=>"2", "owner"=>"blue moon farms"},
              {"name"=>"eddie", "id"=>"3", "owner"=>"sunrise farms"}],
     "cows"=>[{"name"=>"dee", "id"=>"3", "owner "=>"black hat farms "},
              {"name"=>"sunny", "id"=>"2", "owner "=>"blue moon farms "},
              {"name"=>"bess", "id"=>"4", "owner "=>"wolcott farms"}]} 
h.each { |k,v| instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v) }
```

We now have:

```
@pigs
  #=> [{"name"=>"peggy", "id"=>"1", "owner"=>"wolcott farms "},
  #    {"name"=>"sue", "id"=>"2", "owner"=>"blue moon farms"},
  #    {"name"=>"eddie", "id"=>"3", "owner"=>"sunrise farms"}] 
@cows
  #=> [{"name"=>"dee", "id"=>"3", "owner "=>"black hat farms "},
  #    {"name"=>"sunny", "id"=>"2", "owner "=>"blue moon farms "},
  #    {"name"=>"bess", "id"=>"4", "owner "=>"wolcott farms"}]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response,I still don't know how do I create an instance variable based on a class that does not exist yet. I want this variable to be named based on the corresponding line.

Comment: You are always in a class. Here, `self #=> main; self.class #=> Object.`